# How to dynamically add controls to a winform

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm trying to add multiple GroupBox on a winform. This is my code :

```
Dim newGroupBox As New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Do
    newGroupBox = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    newGroupBox.Text = Colonnes(indexColonne, 0)
    newGroupBox.Name = "groupBox" & indexColonne
    Nomenclature_Regroupe.Controls.Add(newGroupBox)

    indexColonne = indexColonne + 1
Loop While Colonnes(indexColonne, 0) <> ""
```

It's only adding one control. I know my array `Colonnes` has two entries but it display only one on my `winform`.

I've tried to add them manually, and this is working :

```
Dim indexColonne = 0
Do
    Dim newGroupBox As New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    newGroupBox.Text = Colonnes(0, 0)
    newGroupBox.Name = "groupBox" & indexColonne
    Nomenclature_Regroupe.Controls.Add(newGroupBox)

    Dim newGroupBox2 As New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    newGroupBox.Text = Colonnes(1, 0)
    newGroupBox.Name = "groupBox" & indexColonne
    Nomenclature_Regroupe.Controls.Add(newGroupBox)

    indexColonne = indexColonne + 1
Loop While Colonnes(indexColonne, 0) <> ""
```

How can I use the first loop to add them dynamically ?

Comment: "It's only adding one control." ...given the posted code, 
 it's more likely that all of them are in fact being added, but they are all exactly the same size and in the same POSITION as you are not setting a different [Location](learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.location?view=netframework-4.7.2) for each one.

Comment: Use the first snippet, moving `Dim newGroupBox As New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox` inside the loop (as you did in the second snippet). You don't need to specify the name (unless it's a specific one). You'll also need to define a Size and Location, otherwise your GroupBox controls will be stacked up and you'll just see the one on top.

Comment: I'll try that and give you an update

Comment: Yep, that works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all I had to do was adding a size and a position, like this :

```
Dim indexColonne = 0
Do
    Dim newGroupBox As New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    newGroupBox.Text = Colonnes(0, 0)
    newGroupBox.Name = "groupBox" & indexColonne
    newGroupBox.AutoSize = True
    newGroupBox.Left = 100 * indexColonne
    Nomenclature_Regroupe.Controls.Add(newGroupBox)

    indexColonne = indexColonne + 1
Loop While Colonnes(indexColonne, 0) <> ""
```